# Image passed in a function is not displaying in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a image displayed in small icon , when I click on the image , I want to pass the `imagesource` in a function `showPhotos()` and display it in popup. I tried doing it , but my popup is coming empty without photos.

My thumbnail image html:

```
 <div class="image" ng-repeat="image in filteredImages track by $index">

         <div class="dropdown">
        <img ng-src="{{image.source}}" class="images" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showPhotos(image.source)"/>
                   </div>
              </div>
```

JS:

```
     $scope.model.selectedImage = "";
    $scope.showPhotos = function(image) {
          $scope.model.selectedImage = image;
            $('#imagePreview').modal('show');
        }
```

ImagePreview Modal Html :

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="imagePreview" role="dialog"  data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style="padding-top: 3em;">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <div class="modal-content imagemodal" style="text-align: center;">

                    <div class="modal-body" style="background: #eee;">


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="image" >
                  <img class="imagePreview" ng-src="{{model.selectedImage}}"/>

            </div>
        </div>
           </div>
            </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: are u using `UI-Bootstrap `

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No errors. Image is having value , but it is not displaying in imagePreview modal. Inside the imagePreview it says undefined

Comment: the code posted above looks fine, make sure you have defined `$scope.model = {}`. If you can recreate issue in fiddle that would be easy for us.